# Pull dynamic content from jQuery load div iframe

Tags: jquery

How can I pull the dynamic content from another page's DIV of same domain using jQuery load function like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#bres" ).load( "http://www.mydomain.com/front-desk #b_col" );
});

<div id="bres"></div>
```

`http://www.mydomain.com/front-desk` is a page

this is not working, is there anyway how I can achieve this? I tried this few years ago which worked but not its not working.

Comment: @MackieeE, you are wrong. _"The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded."_

Comment: It should work just fine, please try to elaborate some more about with exactly doesn't work. Also make sure the id is the right id and it's included in the static page.

Comment: @gdoron aye, checked the docs and it's in the same argument indeed apologies :]